# Having trouble converting my Barker notation scheme to SQL script

Tags: sql, datatable, sqlplus

[image]

I have this scheme written in Barker's notation for my database class. I am new to SQL and I have to write a script that will create the SQL equivalent of this scheme. I am having a lot of trouble with it especially how to write the relationships between tables into SQL code.

Could anyone help me with writing that script?

Also the scheme is in French so if you need me to translate, feel free to ask.

Comment: As the syntax for creating tables with primary/foreign keys is DBMS-specific, please tag you question with the DBMS you are targeting. Having read the documentation for your DBMS, what specific question do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Automobile(
    auto_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    auto_immatriculation,
    PRIMARY KEY(auto_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Piece(
    part_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    part_nom VARCHAR(64),
    part_description VARCHAR(512),
    PRIMARY KEY(part_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Detail_vehicule(
    detail_nbre_sieges varchar(64),
    detail_auto_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    PRIMARY KEY(detail_auto_id)
);
```

Since I do not speak French, I'm not sure what exactly is needed, but, if you need to create a foreign key, then this is the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

If you have 1:1 relations, that is, for example, an Automobile has a single correspondent Detail_vehicule, and vice-versa, then you create a foreign key for Automobile referencing Detail_vehicule and a foreign key for Detail_vehicule, referencing Automobile.

If, instead of 1:1, you have a 1:n (one-to-many) relationship, then you create a foreign key at the "many" table referencing the "one".

Finally, if you have an m:n (many-to-many) relationship, then you need to create a table referencing both other tables with a foreign key each. Example:

You may have t1(id, ...) and t2(id, ...) tables which have a many-to-many relationship. You therefore need to create a t1_t2(t1_id, t2_id) table, with two foreign keys, t1_id referencing t1.id and t2_id referencing t2.id.